# KDE: Assigning hotkeys to switch to specific running programs

Tags: kde, hotkeys

I have some programs always running, such as my main terminal, browser and so on. Is there a way to assign a hotkey that lets me switch to a specific running program?

Using Kubuntu (11.10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up global key shortcuts for [wmctrl](http://enwp.org/wmctrl).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.